# javascript error in firefox "container is not defined"

Tags: javascript, firefox

I am getting a weird JavaScript error in firefox 8.0,  when I click on the firebug icon to show the console. it says "Container is not defined". There are 2 other error which comeup on pageload, they are 
jQuery is not defined .......................jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js
jQuery("#radioGraphsWorkflow").buttonset is not a function ....dashboard.js
Container is not defined..................................http://www.google.com/uds/api/visualization/1.0/92cbb0f92b037d8f5681d4066f62a719/format+en,default,corechart.I.js

The errors are coming up as a result of revamping the style template to use constellation template - a new template, which I am guessing internally uses google charts for visualization - (source of third error)

the template we are using is this one:
http://themeforest.net/item/constellation-complete-admin-skin/116461

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This error is usually caused (when using the Google chart API) by elements which share an ID. Ensure that there are no duplicate IDs.

You can use the [w3 validator](http://validator.w3.org/) to check this.

The other alternative is that the container genuinely doesn't exist. Check that the container which you're applying the div to actually exists